# Crawlspider to parse and add links from XML pages on the way

Tags: scrapy

I have created a crawlspider for my needs it works perfectly. However there are certain xml sitemaps on some categories(not in all) on the site I am crawling. So I would like to have the feature to parse .xml sitemap on these categories and get links then leave it to the crawlspider to go deeper to those links.

I am aware that there is a SitemapSpider and XMLFeedSpider however I need the functionality of crawlspider with XMLFeedSpider or vice-versa.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make CrawlSpider work with URLs in sitemaps, you can cook up a custom link extractor for XML responses, but it looks like
[`CrawlSpider` does not process XML responses](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/75cd056223a5a8da87a361aee42a541afcf27553/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L52). So you also need to override `_requests_to_follow` to accept them.

Here's an example spider I tried with a `sitemap.gz` URL to start with (containing a sitemapindex)

```
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.link import Link
from scrapy.http import Request


class XmlLinkExtractor():

    def __init__(self, xpath, namespaces):
        self.xpath = xpath
        self.namespaces = namespaces

    def extract_links(self, response):
        selector = response.selector
        if self.namespaces:
            for i, ns in self.namespaces.items():
                selector.register_namespace(i, ns)
        for link in selector.xpath(self.xpath).extract():
            yield Link(link)


class ExampleSitemapCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = (
        # link to a sitemap index file
        'http://www.example.com/sitemap.gz',

        # link to a sitemap file
        #'http://www.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap-general.xml',
        )
    rules = (

        # this handles sitemap indexes, following links to other sitemaps
        Rule(XmlLinkExtractor('/sm:sitemapindex/sm:sitemap/sm:loc/text()',
                {"sm": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}),),

        # this is for "leaf" pages in sitemaps
        Rule(XmlLinkExtractor('/sm:urlset/sm:url/sm:loc/text()',
                {"sm": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}),
            # here, defining the callback without follow=True
            # makes the crawler stop at these pages level,
            # not following deeper links
            # unset the callback if you want those pages
            # to go through other rules once downloaded
            callback='parse_loc'),
        # ... other rules
    )

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        # we need to override `_requests_to_follow`
        # and comment these 2 lines, because they filter XML responses
        #if not isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
        #    return
        seen = set()
        for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                     if lnk not in seen]
            if links and rule.process_links:
                links = rule.process_links(links)
            for link in links:
                seen.add(link)
                r = Request(url=link.url, callback=self._response_downloaded)
                r.meta.update(rule=n, link_text=link.text)
                yield rule.process_request(r)

    def parse_loc(self, response):
        self.logger.debug("parsing %r" % response)
```

Depending on how you want to parse pages from `/urlset/url/loc`, you may want to redirect different URLs to different callbacks (adding different Rules, and customizing `XmlLinkExtractor` to allow filtering (or use XPath to filter)

Comment: Thanks Paul, also another thing that I have noticed is that Steven has also the correct answer. The problem exists when I start off with xml pages( if i set the start_urls as xml) in crawlspider. If I start off with a html page then make it go to a xml page the crawlspider seems to be doing the trick with Steven's answer. Thank you all for helping out. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a rule to your current CrawlSpider and parse the XML yourself. You just need to add a rule at the top of `rules` and edit `sitemap_xml_xpath` in the callback:

```
import scrapy
import scrapy.linkextractors
import scrapy.spiders.crawl


class SmartlipoSpider(scrapy.spiders.crawl.CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ('http://example.com/',)
    rules = (
        scrapy.spiders.crawl.Rule(
            scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'sitemap\.xml$',
            ),
            callback='parse_sitemap_xml', follow=True,
        ),
        # the other rules...
    )

    def parse_sitemap_xml(self, response):
        sitemap_xml_xpath = '/urlset/url'

        for url in response.xpath(sitemap_xml_xpath):
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    # your other callbacks...
```

Comment: I have tried this before the response thats coming to parse_sitemap_xml seems to be null. Its not treated as HTML as expected.

Comment: Crawlspider doesnt return the xml results. response comes empty for some reason or when i start_url an xml page the above code doesnt run the parse_sitemap_xml.